# How to open .desktop file with a URL in Fedora?

Tags: command-line, fedora, application-launch

I have a `.desktop` file with this content:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Link
Name=FileName
URL=https://example.com
```

that I would like to launch in my default browser from the command line.

How can I do that? I tried `gtk-launch`, but it says "no such application":

```
[bf@localhost Playground]$ gtk-launch Somelink.desktop 
gtk-launch: no such application Somelink.desktop

[bf@localhost Playground]$ gtk-launch /home/bf/Playground/Somelink.desktop 
gtk-launch: no such application /home/bf/Playground/Somelink.desktop
```

Comment: Might [this](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/393079/gtk-launch-only-works-when-present-working-directory-is-desktop) or [this](https://www.reddit.com/r/Fedora/comments/huqpq2/custom_desktop_files_not_working_on_fedora_32/) help?

Comment: @Peregrino69 No, I tried all these things

Comment: Dang. Could you please update your question with what exactly you've tried so others don't offer more already-tested solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All usual solutions somehow do not work on my system, so I just use this command now:

```
~$ google-chrome `grep -oe http.* somefile.desktop`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try :
`xdg-open Somelink.desktop`

Not tested in Fedora, but works on my openSUSE.

In case you don't have `xdg-open` available, it seems that you could install the `xdg-utils` package.

Source : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5116473/linux-command-to-open-url-in-default-browser

Comment: I tried, it doesn't work. I have created my own small script now to handle this.